# IQKeyboardManager scrolls whole screen but want to scroll only tableview content

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, iqkeyboardmanager

In My Chatting App `textFieldDidBeginEditing` adds keyboard height automatic using `IQKeyboardManager` but it scrolls whole screen to top. I have a requirement to only scroll tableView's content. My `navigationBar` should stay attached to top but using third party scroll library (IQKeyboardManager) scrolls all part in top. So How can I only scroll the `tableView` content?

Answer (score 1):

In your `ChatViewController` you can disable `IQKeyboardManager`.

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnabled = false
   IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnableAutoToolbar = false
}
```

You can re-enable it when you are about to leave that view-controller like this.

```swift
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnabled = true
    IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnableAutoToolbar = true
}
```

Now that we are disabling `IQKeyboardManager` we have to manage the keyboard our-selves.

To do that you can try below approach.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    prepareTableView()
    observeKeyboardEvents()
}
```

Here you call the `observeKeyboardEvents` method in `viewDidLoad` method.

```swift
private func observeKeyboardEvents() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] (notification) in
        guard let keyboardHeight = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else { return }
        print("Keyboard height in KeyboardWillShow method: \(keyboardHeight.height)")
        self?.tableView.contentInset.bottom = keyboardHeight.height + 8
        self?.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = keyboardHeight.height + 8
        }

     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] (notification) in
         self?.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = 0 + 8
         self?.tableView.contentInset.bottom = 0 + 8
     }
}
```

> In `observeKeyboardEvents` method, you register this view-controller to observe the Keyboard `Appear` and `Disappear` notifications and adjust your `tableView`'s `contentInset.bottom` accordingly. So we should also remove this view-controller to stop receiving keyboard events notification. For that you can try below code.

```swift
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Hope, this might help you. :)

Comment: I have tried the same but now my textfield is not moving up and with this user is unable to check the message typed.